# Populate db for development purposes

Tags: jhipster

Of course I can read JSON with Jackson and save it to db but it seems to be a common task so maybe there is a tool for this. I don't want SQL. I want something higher level and more convenient like fixtures in Django.

Comment: Can you expand your question? I'm not sure what you are looking to do

Comment: @JonRuddell I'm looking for a way to provide data for db in db independant format for testing and frontend development. I think the reference to Django makes it clear. Quite a common task to have a tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

With phpmyadmin you can add a row in your db and easily insert also a JSON as BLOB (for example).